# How to delay the disappearance of elementui tooltip components,

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I used the elementui tooltip component, and I saw that only delayed display by 'open-delay', how to make it delay disappear

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `hide-after` property ? Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/58mdw0et/

If you want to delay when the mouse leaves the element, first use the `manual` property on `el-tooltip`. Then use mousenter and mouseleave envents (in case of an el-button) to show/hide the tooltip. You can use for example `debounce` method from lodash in order to delay the hide method. Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/qrt3pbqm/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I mean, when my mouse is in the target area, tooltip always shows, and when my mouse moves out of the target area, it delay disappearance,i tried 'hide-after' but when my mouse moves out of the target area it disappear immediately